# google analytics landing page=(not set)

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

In report `All Traffic`,If  i choose primary dimension as `"Landing Page"` i see some (not set) entries.
Why it may happen?
Also it entries have `page/visits=0, % new visits < 2% and bounce rate = 0%.`

Comment: This question is off topic for SO, you should try http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Are you filtering out pageviews, but events or social interactions are still going through the filters and hitting GA, spawning new visits that don't have pageviews? Then (not set) might mean that the dimensions you're combining don't have a real relationship.  Another reason might be data that GA couldn't lookup for that dimension and there are some different reasons that might happen.

http://analytics.blogspot.com/2009/08/back-to-basics-not-set-entries.html
http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2820717